# Excel: Using VBA to apply conditional formatting to blank cells in individula columns

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have applied the duplicate conditional format to columns AB, AD, AR, AT, BH & BJ across a worksheet with around 1500 rows, however it is also highlighting the blanks.

I have tried to create an additional conditional format of changing any of the blanks to a white cell colour, as I can't find a way to remove the conditional format from the blank cells.

The only way I have found to highlight the cells white at the moment is to use the conditional formatting again, which works perfectly when I record the macro but not when I replay this as it turns either the whole column white, or leaves blank cells as red.

This is the vba code of the additional conditional format:

```
Sub Macro3()    
    Range("I:I,AB:AB,AD:AD,AR:AR,AT:AT,BH:BH,BJ:BJ").Select
    Range("BJ1").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=LEN(TRIM(BJ1))=0"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```

Help is greatly appreciated as I've spent far too long trying to find a work around!

Comment: If you want to self reference then start at the *top left cell*, so `Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=LEN(TRIM(i1))=0"`

Comment: Hi I've tried that, but it still gives me blank cells that are highlighted with the duplicate colour?

Answer (score 1):

Try add another filter with formula `isblank=true` for the same cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Macro3()
    Range("I:I,AB:AB,AD:AD,AR:AR,AT:AT,BH:BH,BJ:BJ").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=LEN(TRIM(I1))=0"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```